# How to create wizard/screens with disabled pages/buttons using Dojo Dijit?

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

I want to create a sequence of screens using a StackContainer in Dijit.

However, I want to disable consecutive pages and their corresponding buttons in the StackController until the form on the current page has been validated successfully.

Is this possible with the standard elements? If so, how?

In addition, it would be nice if I could customize the buttons of the StackController to show my own details instead of the title of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For disabling I think you can use

```
the_button.set('disabled', true); //and vice-versa
```

For changing the details you can try setting the labels directly (similar to disabled) or try subclassing the appropriate stuff (probably the stackcontroller) if it turs out to be feasible.

Comment: Yes, that works. I was thinking I was going to have to extend the StackController or something, but I can work with this. Thanks.